# Arabic_CI_AS is not displayed correctly

Tags: java, sql-server, servlets, encoding, character-encoding

I am using SQL Server database with character encoding `Arabic_CI_AS`
and I have HTML page whose character encoding is utf-8.

And this page communicates with servlet to get data from the database and displays them in the page again, my issue is that the Arabic data is displayed as `???????` in the page.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

This issue is related with Unicode and collation.

When you write (insert/update) to the table you have to add the "N"  in front of all text, char, varchar, nchar and Nvarchar data types. And on top of that, the datatype of every column in that table has to be either Nchar or Nvarchar. Keep in mind TEXT data type has been deprecated, so you get a chance you can change it to Nvarchar (MAX).

Sample:

```
insert into table_name ( name , address ) 
values ( N'John', N'123 abc dr.')
```

When you read from this table you will get what you write, unless the name and address column data type are other than Nchar, Nvarchar.
If you don't put "N" in front and/or the datatype is different from the above, for sure you will get ???, whenever you work with NON_ASCI characters (non-English).

Answer (score 0):

**user3571015** is right, you must be sure your data is saved correctly.

Try to use "collate"

```
SELECT  (yourColumn) 
FROM yourTable
WHERE yourColumn COLLATE Arabic_CI_AS   = 'yourText'
```